# Is there a good tool for documenting/monitoring System Tests?

Tags: testing, trac, system-testing

I'm looking for a tool to design, document, and monitor System Tests for a product.

The basics of what I need are:
1) A tool that can represent some kind of Inheritance between tests (i.e., one test which sets up another or somesuch).

2) A tool that will allow me to monitor specific runs of the tests seperately, per version (i.e., for version 1.1 of the product, we ran these specific tests from all the tests that are documented).

3) A tool which will allow some kind of freeform "tagging" of tests (i.e., I can group the same test into several groups: Regression tests, functionality test, ui test... one test can be all three at once).

4) Optional - The tool will allow me to run "automatic tests" scripts (automated using an automation system developed in-house, so it has to allow lots of ways to tie-in to it).

One tool I found that might work is: http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TestCaseManagementPlugin

It has the added benefit of working with Trac, which we are starting to use for bug tracking/missiong tracking. If anyone can recommend (or give a good reason not to use it), it would also be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[TestLink](http://testlink.sourceforge.net/docs/testLink.php) is a nice open source tool for system test management; it's widely used, under active development and has Trac integration.  It should do most of what you need.

Comment: Looking at TestLink, it is just a management tool for recording test info and managing testers? It doesn't seem to actually run tests (despite the misleading term "execution").

Comment: @Andy: It does have Execution capacities, you require a XMLRPC server running which could execute tests for you. I am the one who contributed this particular feature to Testlink.